# is it necessary to synchronize I/O operation in Android

Tags: android, io, synchronization

In [volley](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley) code, I/O operations (get/put) in DiskBasedCache are synchronized, I am not sure if it is necessary. Networking threads handle different URLs, so will write to different files. If we can make sure reading thread won't read the files being writing, is it OK to remove the synchronization for better performance?

Comment: `f we can make sure reading thread won't read the files being writing` i think its OK to remove `synchronize`

Answer (score 0):

Synchronisation allows the objects to be passed to different threads safely. Note that synchronisation without contention on I/O operations will not be a bottle neck in most cases.

DiskBasedCache - here synchonisation is necessary if this cache is used by multiple threads to avoid data races.